# Custom iOS Target properties key values cannot be read from Swift code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create 2 build configurations for my App.

I've made a directory "Config" and added 2 files:

Debug.xcconfig

Release.xcconfig

[image]

I've added below code to these files:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-COMPANY_NAME4/Pods-COMPANY_NAME4.debug.xcconfig"

COMPANY_NAME4_APP_NAME = COMPANY_NAME4 Acc
COMPANY_NAME4_API = api.companyname.nl
COMPANY_NAME4_BUNDLE_ID = nl.companyname4.acc.app
COMPANY_NAME4_APP_ICON = AppIconDebug
```

I've changed the Custom iOS Target Properties to include these custom parameters:

[image]

I see these values as well in my info.plist:

[image]

When calling this method:

```
print("value name = " + LoginApiImpl.getKeyForBuildVariant("CompanyName4Url"))


static func getKeyForBuildVariant(_ key: String) -> String {
    return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: key) as! String
}
```

This returns:

```
value name = "https:
```

and it should return:

```
value name = api.companyname.nl
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need to do the following

- click on the target on the top panel as below and you will get the target list you have

[image]

[image: Target Membership selection]

- goto the target membership for the selected file on the right panel
- and for each file make sure to select the only target/s who would be the owner for the file  as in second image

[image]

- and through this you can actually write the same code and guarantee that the data will be as per target

Comment: I don't understand how to get there, click edit scheme?

Comment: edited the answer and added the place you can click so you cane get the target list

Comment: sorry fo late reply .. new scheme if you don't have one

Comment: it doesn't say "On demand resource Tags" but "Project Document"

Comment: target membership is available once any document from the left panel is selected for instance .xib file or .swift file and so on

Comment: But the problem is that the code doesn't return the correct string for a given key. Why would changing these settings help with that?